# Does GitLab's `rules:changes` allow for both relative and absolute paths?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Taking this example directly from [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges).

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        - Dockerfile
```

1. Is this reference to `Dockerfile` is an absolute (from the root of the repository) reference to `/Dockerfile` or is it a reference to `**/Dockerfile` (zero or more directories deep)?
2. If this is an absolute reference, how can I specify the `**/Dockerfile` version?
3. Else, if this is aa reference to `**/Dockerfile`, how do I specify the absolute `/Dockerfile` version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `Dockerfile` is an "absolute path" only matching `/Dockerfile`.

Precisely speaking: [paths are *relative to the root of the project directory*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists). Which you can think of as "absolute" for simplicity's sake.

(But technically in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline your code gets checked out on some computer by a [Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) (program who runs your pipelines), which does *not* copy your project files to the machine's filesystem root. The paths that you define are thus not really [absolute by a strict definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths).)

> I linked the docs of [`rules:exists`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists) there, because it's only stated explicitly in some parts of the documentation, as on [`artifacts:paths`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactspaths) as well. But you'll find that this is usually the behaviour of these paths keys. (Under the hood in your example you're specifying a paths key, too: [`rules:changes:paths`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschangespaths). You're just using the shorthand notation there [as the last bullet point below the example states](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges)).

To match files anywhere in the project (zero or more directories deep) [you need to use wildcard characters and wrap the path in double quotes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges): `"**/Dockerfile"` (last point before the example in the linked docs).

> The wrapping in double quotes is prescribed by the documentation, because else the YAML parser might misinterpret your path as a [YAML alias referencing a YAML anchor](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) defined with `&*/Dockerfile` (yes, [`*` and `/` are valid there](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/)). I guess you don't have such a YAML anchor defined, but it's good to take this precaution.